# get data-src content from the iframe of the active slide, then write an src attribute instead with this content

Tags: iframe, find, src, attr, vimeo-api

```
<iframe class="lazyload iframevimeocover" width="100%" top="-50%" left="-50%" 
data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/https://vimeo.com/337332051&background=1&muted=1&autoplay=0&loop=1&controls=0&autopause=0&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&transparent=0&gesture=media&dnt=1&quality=1080p" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media; fullscreen;" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

**I use *lazysizes* to lazyload.

when it is loaded, ".lazyloaded.iframevimeocover" is the iframe class.**

**On the code below, I get this error in the console:****

*TypeError: slideActive.find('.lazyloaded.iframevimeocover').get(0).attr is not a function. (In 'slideActive.find('.lazyloaded.iframevimeocover').get(0).attr('data-src')', 'slideActive.find('.lazyloaded.iframevimeocover').get(0).attr' is undefined)*

**I didn't find what I need to change to avoid this error ?**

**actual code:**

```
  //// replace data-src to src, and play video from active slide ////


    // select active slide
    var slideActive = $('.swiper-slide').eq(swiper.activeIndex);
    
    // get content from "data-src" attribute           
    let dataSrc = slideActive.find('.lazyloaded.iframevimeocover').get(0).attr('data-src');
    
    // write in the iframe a new attribute 'src' with all the dataSrc content inside
    slideActive.find('.lazyloaded.iframevimeocover').get(0).attr('src', dataSrc);

    // create a new player                  
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(slideActive.find('.lazyloaded.iframevimeocover').get(0));
    
    // play player
    player.play();
```